# jquery inserted element class not loaded

Tags: jquery, class

I'm removing the rows from a table and then reinserting them after user has made some edits on a form; poblem is

```
class="view_dialog"
```

is not "loaded" for the inserted rows.

the original row has this layout:

```
<tr>
    <td>new one</td>
    <td>B2B NFIB</td>
    <td class="actions" id="actions">
       <a href="/dirs/edit/252" class="view_dialog">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Once user changed some things, I remove all rows (usually just 3 of 4) and use jquery to populate the table (.records):

```
$('.records tbody tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+data.dirArray[$count].Dir.name+'</td><td>'+data.dirArray[$count].Dir.dir_description+'</td><td class="actions" id="actions"><a href="/dirs/edit/'+data.dirArray[$count].Dir.id+'" class="view_dialog" id="Edit'+data.dirArray[$count].Dir.id+'">Edit</a></td></tr>');
```

Rows are created just fine and the generated code for the rows is identical to the original (add id trying to use .addClass to no luck)

```
<tr>
    <td>new one</td>
    <td>B2B NFIB</td>
    <td class="actions" id="actions">
        <a href="/dirs/edit/252" class="view_dialog" id="Edit252">Edit</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Why is the class not "loaded". I'm using that class to trigger some events.

Tried

```
$("[id^=Edit]").addClass('view_dialog');
```

to no results.

Checked .live but it has to do with parent-children controls. Is it mandatory to use in this case?

Can you help?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you sure the class isn't set? What do you see when you look at the DOM in Firebug or Developer Tools? I think it's more likely that the problem is that the new element doesn't have events bound to it, because you bound the events before the row was added.

Comment: have you tried using .delegate() instead of .live() ? .live() is deprecated anyway as of jQuery 1.7 . http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @supernova "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click bindings only apply to elements that are in the DOM at the time you create them, not elements that get added later. To handle elements that are added dynamically, you need to delegate with this:

```
$(".records").on("click", ".view_dialog", function() {
    alert('class clicked');
});
```

Comment: A big Thank you, @Barmar! It does work.
I need to do the same to another added element, say "[id^=deleteAd]". I tried delegating from the same class (.records) and did not work.
Is not clear to me why $(".records").on("click", ".view_dialog"
works. given .records does not have any "click" event defined in the first place. Also, to have it working, I had to dupplicate the code on my .view_dialog click function. I can live with that of course  (sigh).
What do you suggest to have this work for "[id^=deleteAd]" (or ".deleteAd" class) which is also on the .records table?

Thank you so much.

Comment: To answer your first question: it works because `.on` creates the click event handler for .records; the handler checks whether the click is within a .view_dialog element, which is how it works for elements added after the handler. I don't know why the same isn't working for .deleteAd -- maybe post a new question with the full details.

Answer (score -1):

Have you enclosed the code in DOM Ready event

```
$(function() {

   // You code 
   $("[id^=Edit]").addClass('view_dialog'); 

});
```

Also when are you adding the class.. It is before creating the elements or after creating them..

If you are assigning this before the elements are created , I am afraid this will not help in the case of newly added elements..

You need to explicitly add the class on each newly created element.

Comment: He said the rows are being added. And you can see in his Javascript that the class is included.

Comment: I call 

$("[id^=Edit]").addClass('view_dialog');

righ after creating the <tr>

@Barmar, 
I do have an event bind to class view_dialog:

    $(".view_dialog").click(function()
    {
        alert('class clicked');
        $("#view_dialog").load($(this).attr('href'), function(response, status, xhr) {
        etc....
    }

I've inspected the DOM afterwards and the rows look fine, with the id added. It seems like addclass is not being triggered.  :-(

Comment: @supernova, how would I use .on or .live to solve this? Thanks !!

Comment: Did you try with $("[id*=Edit]")